# Keras multi-class classification process taking a long time

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I started learning how to use Keras. I have a raw file that encodes ASCII values of characters in a sentence with a corresponding product name. For example, `abcd toothpaste cream` would be classified as `Toothpaste`. The first two lines (out of ~150,000 lines) of the code is shown below. The file is also available for download [here](https://files.fm/u/3bry35w6) (this link will last two months from today).

```
12,15,11,31,30,15,0,26,28,15,29,30,19,17,15,0,19,24,30,15,28,24,11,30,0,18,19,17,19,15,24,15,0,35,0,12,15,22,22,15,36,11,0,12,15,22,22,15,36,11,0,16,28,11,17,11,24,13,19,11,29,0,16,15,23,15,24,19,24,11,29,0,11,36,36,15,14,19,24,15,0,11,36,36,15,14,19,24,15,11,22,11,19,11,0,26,15,28,16,31,23,15,0,16,15,23,15,24,19,24,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Body Care Other
12,15,19,15,28,29,14,25,28,16,0,30,18,11,19,22,11,24,14,0,13,25,0,22,30,14,0,29,21,19,24,13,11,28,15,0,26,28,15,26,11,28,11,30,19,25,24,29,0,16,11,13,19,11,22,0,13,22,15,11,24,29,15,28,29,0,24,19,32,15,11,0,16,11,13,19,11,22,0,13,22,15,11,24,29,15,28,29,0,26,28,25,14,31,13,30,29,0,24,19,32,15,11,0,23,11,21,15,0,31,26,0,13,22,15,11,28,0,23,19,13,15,22,22,11,28,0,33,11,30,15,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Skin Care Other
```

I am following a [blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) where it uses a simple deep learning Keras model to do multi-class classification. I changed the configuration of the neural network to `243 inputs --> [100 hidden nodes] --> 67 outputs` (because I have 67 classes to classify). The code is below:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()

    # I changed it to 243 inputs --> [100 hidden nodes] --> 67 outputs (because I have 67 classes to classify)
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X_len, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(Y_cnt, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("./input/raw_mappings.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_len = len(dataset[0,:-1])
X = dataset[:,0:X_len].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,X_len]
Y_cnt = len(numpy.unique(Y))

# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)


estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

But it never seems to finish when I ran it on my desktop computer for more than 12 hours. I'm starting to think there is almost nothing going on. Is there something that I'm doing wrong with either the configuration of the neural network or the problem I'm trying to solve (meaning, maybe `Sequential model` is not the right way to go for classifying `>60` classes?).

Any pointer or tip would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by 'never seems to finish'. I also do not know why you are using sklearn-like wrappers around keras to do this instead of just calling `.fit` on your resulting model. It does not look like you are even ever fitting.

Comment: @modesitt I meant 'never finishes' as in the program keeps running (CPU is being used for sure) without nothing returned [https://imgur.com/a/a7TjsTP]. I'm still learning about Keras, and simply just following the blog post I mentioned above. If you have a suggestion on how I can change the code to start fitting, saving the model and predicting, please let me know. Thank you!